# optimizing form submission speed in asp.net javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms, web-config

i am currently working on one asp.net application and try to post one form data ,while i use the following code it gets delayed in form submission :

```
 window.document.frmlogin.action = "LoginCheck.aspx"
            window.document.frmlogin.method = "post"
            window.document.frmlogin.submit()
```

and my webconfig file is as follows :

```
<appSettings/>
<connectionStrings/>
<system.web>

    <compilation  debug="true" >

    </compilation>
<!--
  The <authentication> section enables configuration 
  of the security authentication mode used by 
  ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
-->
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<!--
   The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
   of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
   during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
   it enables developers to configure html error pages 
   to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

   <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
     <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
   </customErrors>
-->
</system.web>
```

How can i optimize the above code to submit the quicker form submission